# how to create partition on windows CE device

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce

Is there any tool to create a new partition on windows CE device? 
Device has a NAND flash memory and initially there were two partitions. Using Storage manager in Control Panel I was able to delete one partition but when I want to create it again, I get an error message: "Unable to create partition".

Comment: The tool could work on both Windows CE and Windows Mobile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the source code of Windows CE 6 you get the [`BootPart library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911532.aspx) source code. The location for the source is `WINCE600\PUBLIC\COMMON\OAK\DRIVERS\ETHDBG\BOOTPART`.

Inside Bootpart.cpp you can find the function `BP_OpenPartition` that opens/creates a new partition. It basically adds information to the MBR.

---

The above solution is a bit low level. Here is a way to do it through Win32 API (taken from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windowsce.embedded/browse_thread/thread/39d5f9d596848d44/963a6444f7b78c30?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=failed+to+create+partition+group:microsoft.public.windowsce.*#963a6444f7b78c30)):

- Call [OpenStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912079.aspx) to get a handle to the store
- Dismount the store using [DismountStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914718.aspx)
- [FindFirstPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911931.aspx)/FindNextPartition will iterate over existing partitions and [DeletePartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917058.aspx) will delete those that can be deleted.
- [GetStoreInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912273.aspx) will get you the number of sectors available for creating a new partition (`(STOREINFO.snBiggestPartCreatable`)
- Use [CreatePartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912236.aspx) to create the partition.

All the pointers to the functions and more information about the storage manager can be found here: [Storage Manager Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914929.aspx)

---

You can see that the links I provided indicate that the functions work on both Windows Mobile 6 and Windows CE 6. Non of the functions are new functionality so they should also work with Windows CE 5.

Comment: Supposed to. Try it out. Here is the reference for CE 5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms886165.aspx